# Как удалить картинку из сервера при нажатии на кнопку с помощью AJAX, PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, form

Вот мой код:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var srcImage = $("#srcImg").val();

    $("#deleteF").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url:"delete.php",
      type: "POST", 
      data: ({src: srcImage}),
      success: function(result){
          alert('Файл был успешно удален!');
      }});
     });
 });
</script>

<?php
   $uploadfile = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $fileSrcImage = fopen("srcImage.txt", "w");
        echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
        fwrite($fileSrcImage, $uploadfile);
        fclose($fileSrcImage);

        $fileRead = file("srcImage.txt");

        foreach($fileRead as $lineSrc){
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='src' id='srcImg' value='". $lineSrc ."'/>";
         }
        }
     ?>

  <html>
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="fileForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="52428800" value="30000" />
      <input name="userfile" type="file" id="file" class="inputFile"/>
       <label for="file">Выбрать Фото</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="selectFile"/>
     </form>
      <input type="button" name="deleteF" value="Удалить" id="deleteF"/>
 </html>
```

Файл delete.php

```
   <?php
     unlink($_POST['src']);
   ?>
```

Я в php и ajax ещё совсем новичок, поэтому заранее извините. Я хочу сделать так что бы файл (в моем случае картинка например) загруженный на сервер, можно было при нажатии на кнопку удалить. В корне проекта есть файл `srcImage.txt` в нём, при загрузке картинки, записываеться название этой картинки, а затем я считываю этот файл и передаю через DOM назание фото, через `<input type="hidden"/>` и как значение, записываю ссылку на само фото(это мне так же нужно для того что бы я мог отобразить картинку в диве), ссылку на фотку потом записываю в переменную `srcImage` в коде jquery, и через ajax передаю в файл `delete.php` что бы он знал, какую именно картинку ему удалять. Не знаю, может я делаю что-то не правильно, но при нажатии на ту же кнопку удалить, ничего не происходит. Буду очень рад, если кто-то поможет...

Comment: Чтобы локализовать проблему - 1. Вместо `data: ({src: srcImage}),` пропишите `data: {src: srcImage},` 2. В файле `delete.php` пропишите `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Спасибо :D Действительно удаляет, но почему-то после того как перезагружу страницу, фото опять появляеться на сервере..

Comment: Тогда надо более детально разобраться )

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ) Буду разбираться

Comment: Если не получится - обращайтесь. ) Только постарайтесь подробнее описать проблему.